# Jenkins matrix parameters with multiple values?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

As part of automating a legacy deployment process, I'm trying to build a Jenkins pipeline that can, among other operations, execute parameterized builds.

One of those is the ability to execute several commands against given list of services. Given a list of service names, e.g.

```
Mailer
Reporter
DbMigrator
...
```

etc, I'd like to run certain commands against some of those.

Using [Extended Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin), I was able to load this list from a properties file, and display it as a list of checkboxes, however, I am looking for a way I could build a "matrix" parameter with multiple values. My goal is to do something like this:

```
| Service    | Opt1| Opt2|
|------------------------|
| Mailer     | [x] | [ ] |
| Reporter   | [x] | [x] |
| DbMigrator | [ ] | [x] |
| ...        |     |     |
```

So that I can apply several values (Opt1 and/or Opt2) to one parameter (e.g. Mailer).

1. Is there a way in Jenkins to do this?
   or
2. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [matrix project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) which comes bundled with later versions of Jenkins.

You can add a  couple of [groovy axis](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GroovyAxis)

which allows you to do this

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def result = []

def inputFile = new File("/path/to/prop.json")
def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
InputJSON.prop1.each{ result << it }

return result
```

with this sort of JSON

```
{
  "parm1": [
    "Mailer",
    "Reporter",
    "DbMigrator"
  ],
  "parm2": [
    "opt1",
    "opt2"
  ],
  "filter": "parm1=='Mailer'"
}
```

These is also a filter option in the matrix to restrict to various combinations. I was trying to make it evaluate that from the 'filter' property above (creating an environment variable using the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) and another groovy script), so far with no success but you can use a string

```
parm1=='Mailer' || parm2 = 'Opt2'
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'll have to try it, I'll let you know if this works for me!